# Usage of Eclipse PDE API Tooling

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, pde

Several teams in our company use internal framework to build an Eclipse UI. This framework is composed of set of Eclipse plugins.

Our team is responsible for the develpment of this framework and we're looking for some tools that would check API breakage in the further versions of our framework.

For example, we have the following class:

```java
package com.foo.A;

class A {
    public void doSmth() {}
}
```

Currently in MANIFEST we and users of our plugins do not specify any versions of plugin's dependencies (always complining with the latest version).

We'd like to have some warnings from Eclipse if we change something in this class, e.g. change method signature or something else. We'd like Eclipse to suggest us to rise plugin's version in such cases.

I've read the following information about API tooling in Eclipse:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/PDE/API_Tools/User_Guide

But it seems to me that this tooling works only with Eclipse native plugins, but not with our custom developed ones.

If I'm mistaken, could anyone be so kind to explain me how to setup API tooling for our plugins?

Comment: [Thus tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-api-tools/) covers using the API tools in your plugins.

Answer (score 1):

the Eclipse API tooling works also with user bundles. What you should do is take your released framework and define it as baseline. A quick solution is to copy all your build and released to the public bundles in a folder and set the folder as Baseline:

`Window - Preferences - Plug-in Development - API Baselines - [Add Baseline...]`

You can have multiple Baselines if you have to patch older release versions of the framework for example. Be sure to set your `API Errors/Warnings` as you reqire them.

Edit: Of course you should enable API Tooling in all your bundles as described in "Configure Bundles for API Tooling" in the web page you linked!

Comment: The question is that after configuring my projects for API tooling as described in the page I've linked no tags are added to my source code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So for now I have errors like 'The type `<class name>` has been removed from `<plugin name>_<plugin version>`'

Comment: The javadoc tags are **not** generated automatically. This is something you will have to do. From your second comment I take it you've got it working! Removal of a class from your exported packages is an api breakage and the major version of the bundle have to be incremented. The error message you have got should be accompanied by an error message stating you should increment the major version.